# Query Rules in SharePoint 2013 (regex)

Tags: search, query, promoted-links

I have a pretty simple requirement to have a best bet (query rule) come up in a SharePoint 2013 search.  If the phrase "BQS" is included in the search query, I want to display a recommended link.

To accomplish this, i think I need to use the Advanced Query Text Match and a regular expression (regex).  I am not a regex guy, so i'm stumped at the moment.

I am trying to use \b(?i)BQS\b as my criteria (to match if the user searches for BQS, bqs, bQs, looking for BQS, etc).

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a "Advanced Query Text Match" and choose "Query contains one of these phrases". You don't need RegEx. (I mean, you CAN, but you don't have to.)

I blogged this the other day: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2014/03/31/better-best-bets/

Comment: Thank you, of course, the simplest solution stares you right in the face!

Comment: No worries, there is a LOT of power in those pages. It's not all that obvious. RegEx would work too.